# The Walking Saddle Curve and other weirdly moving shapes

Tags: surfaces, polyhedra

The link at the end of this sentence seems to be a video of a [walking saddle curve](https://www.facebook.com/jonathan.solla/videos/4036442701977/).

[image]

Where can we obtain these?
What are more exact parameters of this curve?
What is the relation between wind speed and walking speed for these curves?

The [oloid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oloid) rolls in a weird way.  What are some other shapes with weird movements?

Comment: +2 for the great video link. -1 for the lack of mathematical content in the question.